# How to check if a file exists when it was no file extension? C#

Tags: c#, file, io, exists

The file test has no extension and I need help to either move or rename this file to something with a extension

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\\Users" + Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\test"))
{                                                                 /\
                                               this file has no file extension
}
```

Comment: You forgot the ` \\ ` after `"C:\\Users"`

Comment: Also, when using @"", you do not need to double-escape the backslashes.

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions

Comment: use System.IO.Path.Combine. There also is a recommended way of getting the Desktop directory: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

Answer (score 1):

I created a file named `test` with no extension in the folder `M:\Incoming`.

Running the following code works in both cases:

```
if (File.Exists(@"M:\Incoming\test"))
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");

if (File.Exists(@"M:\\Incoming\\test"))
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
```

When using `@` you do not need to specify two slashes, although it makes no difference anyway in this example.

Output:

> Exists
>
> Exists

Your problem is most likely to be in the way in which you are concatenating the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("directory path");
FileInfo[] f = d.GetFiles("test.*");
if (f.Length > 0)
{
   File.Move(oldPath, newPath);
}
else
{
  //File does not exist
}
```

Also check [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "Try like this" is not an answer. You also didn't try to understand OP's problem, you just answered the title.

Answer (score -1):

Use the directory info to get the list of files in directory, then for those files without extension, remove them.